# Codeigniter second database connection query without object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble using my second database connection is codeigniter.

I have added the connection to database.php

```
$old = $this->load->database('old_portal', TRUE);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `frm_root`";
    $query = $this->old->query($sql);
```

But I am getting an error. I am not sure how to use the old object when wanting to use query()

Comment: no need for `$this->old` just `$old`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = $old->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using multiple databases in CodeIgniter is pretty easy.

https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

You would do it like this;

```
$old = $this->load->database('old', true);
```

Then, you would access this database object, like this;

```
$query = $old->query();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't database() need the second parameter TRUE so it returns an object?